# Hide status bar on app resume

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am trying to hide the status bar in my app.  I'm using c# and Xamarin to build the app.

I have the following method that I call from the Activity OnCreate method:

```
    private void hideBars()
    {
        var decorView = this.Window.DecorView;
        int uiOptions = (int)Android.Views.SystemUiFlags.LayoutStable |
                        (int)Android.Views.SystemUiFlags.LayoutHideNavigation |
                        (int)Android.Views.SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen |
                        (int)Android.Views.SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky;
        decorView.SystemUiVisibility = (Android.Views.StatusBarVisibility)uiOptions;

        ActionBar.Hide();
    }
```

That works fine - when the app loads for the first time the status bar is hidden, but can be swiped down as expected.

If I switch to another app, then resume my original app, the status bar is visible, as is the soft keyboard.  I want the status bar (and the soft keyboard) to be hidden on resume, just as on create.  I have the following method:

```
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        hideBars();
    }
```

but the status bar (and keyboard) still appear on resuming the app.

What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.ForceNotFullscreen);
```

This is from the [android developer docs](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html) on sticky immersion.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);}
}
```

Comment: I believe you need to use target Api level 12 as well. You should be using level 14 so I don't see why it wouldn't work

Comment: Since you already declare the window with the variable decorView. Try using that in place of "Window" or try to use this.Window

Comment: Target API is 21, min 16.  this.Window didn't help.  decorView (this.Window.Decorview) doesn't have .AddFlags.

Comment: I'm stumped then. I'll update the answer with the code.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Tried that in OnWindowFocusChanged - still no joy.   (Note that I'm using c#, not Java - so I tried the c# equivalent).

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help you. I'm pretty stumped on this one. And I understand it was c# I literally copied. I should have edited it. I hope you get this figured out soon.